# SQL Server Linked Server Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have added a linked server in my sql server 2008. I want to fetch data from a table and a table valued function residing on my linked server and join this data on a local table by following below given naming convention.

```sql
<server>.<database>.<schema>.<table>
```

However my first problem is I need to fetch `<server>` part from a table. So when I try to do something like following it fails

```sql
Select * FROM @ServerNameVariable.database.dbo.myTable
```

Any idea how can I form fully qualified linked server table name with a user defined variable ?

My SP is as follows

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_SP    
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NetworkDBName VARCHAR(255) 
    SET @NetworkDBName = '[MyLinkedServerName]'
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here 
    select * from @NetworkDBName + '.' + testDatabase.dbo.Invoice_tb
END
GO
```

Comment: You don't need the `@`.

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sys.servers WHERE server_id > 0` - your linked servers

Comment: But the '@' is a must to use before a user defined variable otherwise the SP won't compile

Comment: Please provide your `sp`

Comment: The SP in the form given about fails to compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use variables in place of database, schema or table names.

Instead you can build and execute dynamic SQL statements, using [sp_ExecuteSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

This example won't work, as the server name is seen as a string and not a server object.

Failed Example

```
/* Anti-pattern.
 * Does not work.
 */
DECLARE @Server    SYSNAME = 'Server001';

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @Server.Database1.dbo.Table1
;
```

This example shows a method that does work.  Here the SQL statement is built as a string, which is then executed.

```
/* Dynamic SQL statement.
 * Will work.
 */
DECLARE @Server    SYSNAME = 'Server001';
DECLARE @Statement    NVARCHAR(255);

SET @Statement = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Server) + '.Database1.dbo.Table1;';

EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @Statement;
```

As ever; please be careful when generating and executing dynamic SQL statements.  You do not want to open yourself up to [SQL injection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx) attacks.  Look into [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) or check the passed server name against the code kindly supplied by @Devart above (SELECT name FROM sys.servers WHERE server_id > 0) before executing.

**EDIT 1:** Added more detail to the paragraph on SQL injection.

**EDIT 2:** Removed square brackets from 2nd example query, replaced with QUOTENAME, as per @TTs comment.

Comment: Rather than enclose the servername (or database, table name etc) manually with rectangular brackets, use the [`QUOTENAME function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms176114.aspx). This function will escape properly in case the name contains rectangular brackets.

Comment: Your answer is reallly detailed which I appreciate. However thing is the server name is saved in a database. And secondly I need to use the result set to join to a local table which makes up data i require

Comment: Re Joining:  You can still do this.  The more I think about it the more I prefer the [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) method.  If you follow that link to MSDN it contains an example with an INNER JOIN.  sp_ExecuteSQL could achieve the same results, you just need to add the join and local table name(s).  Re Name saved in db: I'm not sure I understand this point.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Use the name of link server it will a 4 part qualifier e.g

```
Select * From [Link Server Name ].[Database].[Schema].[Table]
```